# asp:Button navigates to not existing URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a WebForms-Site which is located in a Directory (e.g. /View/site.aspx).

In this site I made an asp:Button with an onClick-Event. The idea is, that if this button is clicked, data which was beforehand written into TextBoxes should be saved.

The problem is that if this Button is clicked, it simply rediricts to a not existing site (/site.aspx - ignoring the directory /View).

I simply tragged the button from the Toolbar, so there should be no error in the code. Button1_Click was generated by double clicking the button in the design window and is not called.

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
```

Thank you!

Edit:
As requested, here is Button1_Click. As I said, it is not called.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //I deleted the saving-part, makes no difference. 
    Console.Write("Button 1 clicked!");
}
```

Comment: Could you show us the method you're using to save?

Comment: What exactly would you like this button click to do? Just save or save and redirect?

Comment: You have `Button1_Click` event handler method in button control, can you show it? I think you're using something like `Response.Redirect` there.

Comment: I included the Button1_Click into the question for you to see. Thanks for your responses!

Comment: I would like to save and then redirect, but the method is never called and there is no redirect to the site i would like to go included in the method yet.

Comment: Can you post more code? Where is <asp:Button situated in the code? In a Repeater? Could you post also Page Directive? Thanks