# asp:Button navigates to not existing site

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a WebForms-Site which is located in a Directory (e.g. /View/site.aspx).

In this site I made an asp:Button with an onClick-Event. The idea is, that if this button is clicked, data which was beforehand written into TextBoxes should be saved.

The problem is that if this Button is clicked, it simply rediricts to a not existing site (/site.aspx - ignoring the directory /View).

I simply tragged the button from the Toolbar, so there should be no error in the code. Button1_Click was generated by double clicking the button in the design window and is not called.

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
```

Thank you!

Edit:
As requested, here is Button1_Click. As I said, it is not called.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //I deleted the saving-part, makes no difference. 
    Button1.Text = "Selected";
}
```

Comment: Is the directory a virtual one or a url rewrite? Anyway try setting `form1.Action = Request.RawUrl;` in the page_load.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [asp:Button navigates to not existing URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47416162/aspbutton-navigates-to-not-existing-url)

Comment: And please do not post duplicate questions.

Comment: I don't know what this code snipped does, but i works perfectly. Mind explaining it? Thank you very much, I will not post duplicates again.

Comment: The snippet set's the form post url to the url you see in the browser instead of the "actual" url used by aspnet.

Answer (score 0):

Check the button code inside form tag or not.

Button code should be inside form tag.

```
  <form runat="server">
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
    </form>
```

Let me know if it helps.